# Can you use Diablo 3 disc to play on multiple accounts?

Tags: diablo-iii, pc

My brother, a couple of friends and I all have battle.net accounts. However we only have diablo 3 starter editions. so my question, is that do I need to purchase the game for all of us in order for everyone to play, or will buying the 1 disc and installing it on all of our computers work to allow us all to play the game. Ive searched for similar questions but no answer has gone into this situation. I'm the only one in the group with the money to buy the game and I only have enough for one game. Will my plan to install the game onto all of the accounts work? or is there no other way to play the game without everyone buying their own game of diablo 3?

Comment: One purchase will result in one full version. The full game can only be tied to one account.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. Each disc only comes with a single license, which needs to be activated. One purchase = one player, on one account. If you want more, you have to buy more copies.

Comment: You could use the discs to install multple copies, but you'd still need to get multiple keys, and well, at that point you may as well just buy multiple copies anyway. I have done this before (I installed from a disc which I had lost the key too, so I had to buy a new key but used the same disc.)

Comment: Sorry for double post, So I did find the key for it, so now I have 1 set of discs and 2 keys :) It it wasn't linked to my information I would sell it/give it away.